can I copy over local changes from a submodule
I have a project and a utility library. The project uses the utility library as a submodule. Works fine. But if I made a change to the library I have to commit it and push it to github. Then 'git submodule update ' in the main project.
Is there some way I can sync local changes without pushing (I manually copy at the moment)

You have several options.
Directly make the change to the library in the submodule of the main project.
Make the change in the library repo, and generate a patch. Apply the patch in the main project submodule.
# If the change has been committed,
cd /path/to/library
git format-patch -1 $commit --stdout > patch.diff
# If the change has not been committed,
git diff > patch.diff    # add --cached if the changed file has been added.
cd /path/to/main/project/submodule
git apply -3 /path/to/library/patch.diff

Make the change and commit it in the submodule, then fetch the commit and check it out in the main project submodule. You can also cherry-pick or merge the commit according to the actual situation.
cd /path/to/main/project/submodule
git fetch /path/to/library $branch
git checkout $commit
# git cherry-pick $commit
# git merge $commit


what is $branch and $commit

@pm100 the branch in the local library repository, and the commit created on this local branch.
